# unexpected behavior of jenkins pipeline script with findbugs plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, findbugs

first configuration:

```
stage('bug') 
     { bat 'mvn findbugs:findbugs'
       bat'mvn test'
       findbugs canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: 
       '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', pattern: 
       '**/target/findbugsXml.xml', unHealthy: ''
     }
```

It works properly in the local environment. local is Windows!
But doesn't work in production (RedHat)

second configuration:

```
step([$class: 'FindBugsPublisher', 
pattern:'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.jenkins\\workspace\\pipeline\\target\\findbugsXml.xml', unstableTotalAll:'0'])
```

This works in the local (Windows) as well as production once I take care about '`\\`'.

Pipeline is also compatible with the plugin I'm using.
I want to know why first configuration is not working in production, when second configuration works in both environment.

First configuration throws build failure with error:

```
No Such DSL method findbugs found.
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Does not work? Meaning do you see any error message?

Comment: yes. it shows error saying .--> 'No such DSL method "findbugs" found' 
while applying first configuration in prod

Answer (score 1):

In the [Pipeline: Nodes and Processes](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/), a `bat` step executes a Executes *Windows* Batch script, not a Linux (RedHat or otherwise)

For ReadHat, replace `bat` [with `sh`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script).

That differs from the [Pipeline Maven Integration Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-maven/), which will translate the maven call into bat or shell process, depending on the execution OS.

Comment: when I'm trying to execute in REDHAT this configuration i used "sh". 
this is working " sh mvn findbugs:findbugs" and creates XML files which are having the reports. but it doesn't create chart. for that it is throwing error " NO DSL method"

script to generate chart: (working in windows only)

findbugs canComputeNew: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: 
       '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', pattern: 
       '**/target/findbugsXml.xml', unHealthy:

Comment: when I use this configuration to render the chart (taken care about slash as in linux it is different):  

step([$class: 'FindBugsPublisher', 
pattern:'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\.jenkins\\workspace\\pipeline\\target\\findbugsXml.xml', unstableTotalAll:'0']

this is working in both flavor once i take care about slash "//"

Comment: @PiyushbhaiSadseliya I think you could use a path like `C:/Users/...`, which would avoid having to use `\\`.